# Getting a file path based on predefined path

Tags: php, jquery

I have an app that displays files in a directory(defined by `$starting_file_path`) and when a directory is clicked I use jquery to `$.post()` the link back to the page and append the contents giving me the contents of the directory that was clicked on. Everything works so far. The only problem is this only works going one directory deep. If I try and click on a directory from the newly added listing it doesnt do anything. I know why this is, its because the path is incorrect. I can not figure out a way to get the path based on the already pre defined parent path.

here is where the path goes `link` is simply the name of the directory

```
include "../app/bootstrap.php";
include "../src/controllers/DisplayContentsController.php";

$data = new DisplayContentsController();
$link = (isset($_POST['link']) ? $_POST['link'] : null);

if ($link != null)
{
    $data->show($twig, $starting_file_path . '/' . $link);
}
else
{
    $data->show($twig, $starting_file_path);
}
```

in the if is where I append the name of the file to the starting path. This works only for the first directory. I need it to work for every one after that. So for instance it works if there is a directory called `css` because the starting path is `../../` but when I click on a folder within `css` say `block_styles` it sends `../../block_styles` which doesnt exist. I need it to send `../../css/block_styles`. Can someone help me find out how to accomplish this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the values that are posted to the server - it sounds like the only value being sent is the last node in the path (eg. the path is `../../css/block_styles` and the browser is sending `block_styles`).

If you want it to send `../../css/block_styles`, then the browser has to know about the full path. You probably need to return the full path from your AJAX call and save it somewhere, sending it along with the next request.

EDIT: Ok, I'm going to try to expand this answer. There are a lot of assumptions here about how you are doing this, because there are not enough details in your question - I don't know what the HTML looks like.

So, assuming that the user is clicking on links (`<a>` tags), it *might* look something like this:

```
<a class="folder" id="../../css">css</a>

<script>

    $("a.folder").on("click", function(event){
        // get the path from the ID of the clicked element
        var path = $(event.currentTarget).attr("id");

        // do your AJAX POST, pass the path value, and update
        // the DOM accordingly...
        $.post(...);
    });
</script>
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if HTML will allow an ID value with `.` and `/` characters in it - if not, encode it using `base64_encode` or your own encoding scheme.

In this example, the ID of every folder `<a>` element will be the full path to the folder it references and the server will receive the full path. All you have to do is ensure that every `<a>` tag has the correct `id` value.

Comment: okay well do you have any idea where I can save this at? Is there no way to get the parent directory and just append it?